# What explains this unexpected size of the object from MongoDb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm testing the limits of storing data in Mongo.

I wrote this test class which inserts 1,000,000 random doubles into an array and stores that document a test collection.

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongo.getCollection("TestEmbedded");
Random random = new Random();
Document document = new Document();
document.append("easyFinder", "oneMillion");
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>(1000000);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    double randomCost = 1000 * random.nextDouble();
    values.add(randomCost);
}
document.append("costs", values);
collection.insertOne(document);
```

Fetching this object in the command line, I see the million records are stored:

```
db.TestEmbedded.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ac6cffc75e5e2a6ffe24cc"), "easyFinder" : "oneMillion", "costs" : [ 102.58052971628796, 522.5775655563692, 537.8794277847542, ... ]}
```

I'm trying to see how close I can get before hitting the [16MB limit BSON size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#limit-bson-document-size) in an effort to demonstrate why we don't store this much data in an embedded document.  I know there's alternatives like 'GridFS' and better ways of modeling this data (which is what we really are doing).

But what perplexed me was the `Object.bsonsize()` operation is showing this document as taking up less than a kilobyte of space:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.TestEmbedded.find())
877
```

So what gives?  Knowing Java uses 8 bytes to store a double and Mongo would have to use at least that much space per data point, why isn't this bson size closer to 8 megabytes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.TestEmbedded.find()` returns not the object, but a database cursor which is of small size.

If you use `Object.bsonsize(db.TestEmbedded.findOne())` instead you will receive the real document bson size.